# Creating array object?

Tags: c++, arrays, object

This is a school project, and I can't use STL( Except string, more like  don't use vector, itterator...). I have to read file, build a object named store, and put some articles object in it.

I have a class store with array of articles:

```
class store {
private: 
    Article *articles; 
    ...
};

void store::add_article(string* s)
{                                
    Article art;  
    art.assign(s);
    articles[this->get_nbArticles()] = art;
    nbArticles++;
}
```

My main's like that

```
main
{
    store mystrore;


    //ProcessFile() built another string **array  then return it 
    string **array = processFile();

    //  loop in array here and can display np

     // but here it crash @ 2nd .. when i make display array[2] in first loop , array[2] is empty... 
    mystrore.add_article(array[i]); 
}
```

Question is: I can loop and display all my article, no problem, but when it time to built article my 2nd article make program crash!!. It look like there's no data in my 2nd article!

What is causing the error and crash?

Comment: Instead of using `string*` you could look at just using `string`. The less pointers you use the less likely it is to crash. Also after allocating an array of `string*` you throw that array away when you re-assign a new value to `array` by calling the function `processFile()`.

Comment: The code does not look like its accurate. If `add_article` is a method defined in class Store, then how are you calling it stand alone? You should ensure you provide us with something that's accurate and compiles.

Comment: `new string*[1000]` allocates 1000 uninitialised pointers; where and how are you initialising them?

Comment: Sorry i forgot put mystrore in front of...mystrore.add_article(array[i]);

Comment: I don't think i can just use string , add_article need 4 string

Comment: "I can't use STL" - begs the question "where did `string` come from?" And Galik is absolutely correct, the first three lines of `main()` are a memory block holding one-thousand indeterminate `string` pointers. That should just read `string **array = processFile();` if `processFile` indeed returns `string**`. Post **all** relevant code that reproduces the problem please.

Comment: update rest of the code

Comment: i've update the code, any1 ?

Comment: Ok i think i find it, at least , it seems to work.


  Think it was because i create static obect in method add_article


Article art; 

now i do it like that and it work

    articles[nbArticles] = *new Article(s);